# Convert html decode (e.g. &gt; and &lt;) to a normal readable text( e.g. > and <)

Tags: c#, php, xml, unity-game-engine

I have data from **SQL database** that contains **xml text** which are being *echoed* with **php script**

For example this:

*No:1|TestName:MachineAlfonso|TestParameter:< asdf/>|TestConnection:1234;*

This data is later being parsed to **Unity** for later uses.

however when i try to print it in unity, 
It somehow converting the **<** to **&lt ;** and the **>** to **&gt ;**

The full output become 

*No:1|TestName:MachineAlfonso|TestParameter:&lt ; asdf/&gt ;|TestConnection:1234;*

Is there any function to print the output to become a human readable sign not as html code?
because those two signs( < and  >) are just some than many other html simple that i want to convert.

this is the C# script i use to print the echoed data

```
   public IEnumerator RefreshData()
   {
        //load the data
        //dataLoader is the link of the echoed php data
        WWW InventoryDatabase = new WWW(dataLoaderURL);

        //wait until its done dowloading
        yield return InventoryDatabase;

        string abc = InventoryDatabase.text;
        Debug.Log("text is: " + abc);
   }
```

Comment: I don't know if there is any html specific method but maybe it is enough for you to use `string.Replace` or `Regex.Replace`?

Comment: Use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string) or System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)

Answer (score 1):

In the end, in order not to waste time, I just use **replace** like @derHugo has suggested.

Hopefully there are better and cleaner ways to do it.
But hey, its a start. ^_^

Here is the code snippets if someone has similar problem:

```
     public IEnumerator RefreshData()
       {
            //load the data
            //dataLoader is the link of the echoed php data
            WWW InventoryDatabase = new WWW(dataLoaderURL);

            //wait until its done dowloading
            yield return InventoryDatabase;

             string temp = InventoryDatabase.text;
                    temp = temp.Replace("&lt;", "asdf");
                    temp = temp.Replace("&gt;", "<");
                    temp = temp.Replace("&amp;", "&");
                    temp = temp.Replace("&quot;", "\"");

            //this "Inventory" contains all the data from the echoed file
            string Inventory =  temp;

            string abc = InventoryDatabase.text;
            Debug.Log("text is: " + Inventory);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try PHP's `htmlentities()` function. It's designed specifically for this purpose:

See more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: I'ld suspect the output the OP gets is rather already the result of this and he is searching for something in Unity to revert it.

Comment: yes...., I use htmlentities() in my php script.
The echo output also fine already (it shows < >).., 
but when i parse this **echo data** to unity it revert back to (&lt ; and &gt ;)

Comment: `htmlentities()` is only used if you output values as/in HTML. Do not use it if you output other formats.